# Sculpting 2 point at the same time

Tags: sculpting

i saw 2 vertex of Brush tool on sculpting but on my blender it just 1 how do i make it 2 ? [image]

im a blender newbie trying to learn please give me some tips how to make that thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enable Mesh Symmetry.
In the photo you've sent the X axis symmetry is on.
[image]

Comment: HOly moly its working OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH i saw many people on youtube they have 2 vertex and now i have one Thanks alot